# Help with an identity in Sogge's book

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading page 60 in Sogge's book "Lecture notes on nonlinear wave equations".
The following identity is proved
$$X(\partial) v \Box v= div (X(\partial)vg_0v'-\frac{1}{2}g_0(v',v')X-v^2\textbf{1}) $$
I'm not understanding the role of the term $v^2\textbf{1}$ ; I mean that according my computations I get $X(\partial) v \Box v= div (X(\partial)vg_0v'-\frac{1}{2}g_0(v',v')X)$, so I'm losting something. Where does that term appear in the comutations for the divergence?

Comment: It's hard to read the writing. Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm talking about the identity (3.11), page 60, in the cited book.